# Use ifelse statement on multiple columns based on column name

Tags: r

I have dataset with columns of raw numbers and percentages; some percentages ended up being more than 100. I'd like to use an ifelse statement to convert any number greater than 100 to 100. However, I'd only like the ifelse statement to apply to columns which have the letters "PCT" in their name.

Here is an example:

```
a <- c(4,6,1210,20, 603, 50)
b <- c(50,60,10,400,311, 40)
bubba <- data.frame(A_NUM=a,
                    A_PCT=b)
```

I'd like the final format to be:

```
a <- c(4,6,1210,20, 603, 50)
b <- c(50,60,10,100,100, 40)

bubba_fixed <- data.frame(A_NUM=a,
                    A_PCT=b)
```

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
bubba <- bubba [ , grepl( "PCT" , names( bubba ) ) ]
bubba <- as.data.frame(lapply(bubba, function(x) ifelse(x > 100, 100, x)))
```

And then cbinding it back to the original dataset.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmin`.  Create an index of columns that have 'PCT' in their column names ('j1'), subset the dataset, loop over the columns (`lapply(...`) and get the `pmin` of the columns with 100 and assign it back to the subset of dataset

```
j1 <- grep("PCT", names(bubba))
bubba[j1] <- lapply(bubba[j1], pmin, 100)
```

`pmin` takes the vectors as arguments.  If the length of one vector is 1, it recycles that to the length of the longer vector, and returns a vector giving parallel minimum of the vectors.  Here, the `pmin` takes each of the column as one argument and the second as 100.

Comment: Maybe worth clarifying why this is better: `pmin(x,y)` is a more efficient way of computing  `ifelse(x > y, y, x)` and it also saves you from having to write every term twice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more direct way without using `lapply`:

```
pct = grepl( "PCT" , names( bubba ))
bubba[, pct][ bubba[, pct] > 100 ] = 100
```

For example:
Applying the two lines above to

```
a <- c(4,6,1210,20, 603, 50)
b <- c(50,60,10,400,311, 40)
bubba <- data.frame(A_NUM=a,
                    A_PCT=b, B_num = a, B_PCT = b+10)

> bubba
  A_NUM A_PCT B_num B_PCT
1     4    50     4    60
2     6    60     6    70
3  1210    10  1210    20
4    20   400    20   410
5   603   311   603   321
6    50    40    50    50
```

results:

```
> bubba
  A_NUM A_PCT B_num B_PCT
1     4    50     4    60
2     6    60     6    70
3  1210    10  1210    20
4    20   100    20   100
5   603   100   603   100
6    50    40    50    50
```